# Are MySQL metadata lines not filtered by the Pager?

Tags: mysql

In Mysql 8.0.28 I've noticed that some metadata lines, such as "N rows in set" are displayed even though they do not match the Pager settings. For instance:

```
mysql> pager grep address
PAGER set to 'grep address'
mysql> show tables;
| customer_address_entity                                |
| customer_address_entity_datetime                       |
| customer_address_entity_decimal                        |
| customer_address_entity_int                            |
| customer_address_entity_text                           |
| customer_address_entity_varchar                        |
| inventory_pickup_location_quote_address                |
| quote_address                                          |
| quote_address_item                                     |
| sales_order_address                                    |
450 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

At what level are these metadata lines added, and at what level is the Pager applied? Are the metadata lines sent as an alternative file descriptor, akin to some [stdmeta file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197809/propose-additional-file-descriptor-stdmeta) or even stderror (as `curl` does with metadata)? Or perhaps is the Pager applied at client level, not on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pager is solely a feature of the mysql client.

The metadata lines are not included in the paged output. They are output to stdout after the pager file handle has been closed.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you Bill.